# Angular $resource always calls success callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an issue with Angular $resource. I use it with our API server with CORS enabled.

No matter what error code server returns (tried 500, 422, 409) resource always calls success callback.

Action in the controller:

```
@SpacePostsService.save { spaceId: @space._id }, @post, @_createSuccess, (errors)=>¬
  @_createError(errors, form)
```

Where SpacePostsService:

```
SpacePostsService = $resource postsUrl, {},¬
  query:¬
    isArray: true¬
    method: 'GET'¬
    responseType: 'json'¬
    transformResponse: (data, headers)->¬
      results = data.results || data¬
      results = [results] unless _.isArray(results)¬
      results
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

PS. For readability purposes I didn't show all the code, SpacePostService is a factory and it's properly injected in to the controller.

Comment: what does the method signature to save look like?

Comment: have you tried `$save`? Also, how do you get the `SpacePostsService` into the controller class? some kind of injection? since you don't seem to get some `undefined doesn't have a method save` it seems to be the right `$resource` somehow. I'm just guessing, but maybe you got into the "instance action" part. Then you should use `….$save { spaceId: @space._id }, @_createSuccess, (errors)=>¬
  @_createError(errors, form)`

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I've updated the question. I can not use instance method as I need to send post params as well. Post is not resource it's just simple object.

Comment: hmm. have you tried accessing the `$promise` object? From there you can inspect the headers of the response, maybe something went wrong somewhere.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I tried accessing $promise but it doesn't help - it still goes to success callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the issue. It turns out I had global interceptor defined in other place:

```
AjaxInProgress =
  request: (config)->
    $rootScope.$broadcast 'ajax:in-progress'
    config
  response: (response)->
    $rootScope.$broadcast 'ajax:finished'
    response
  responseError: (response)->
    $rootScope.$broadcast 'ajax:finished'
    return response
```

The last line in `responseError` method is the most important one - because I didn't reject the promise so Angular thought I recovered from error and it called success callback in the $resource function. I changed last line in the AjaxInProgress to:

```
responseError: (response)->
    $rootScope.$broadcast 'ajax:finished'
    $q.reject(response)
```

It solved the problem.

Thank you guys for your help.